# POPAuthenticationError - Mailman Error when polling from Gmail account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, mailman

I am trying to enable my Rails application to receive email from a Gmail Account. I follow this screencast : [Receiving Email with Mailman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2Wunhj-EVg) .

I tried to the the polling for emails from my Gmail account, so that everytime somebody send an email, my app will receive the message and then update the database with this message accordingly.

But when I tried to run 'script/mailman_serve' to start the server and the polling, I got an error like this one below:

```
olins-MacBook-Pro:rentlord Ryzal$ script/mailman_server
I, [2016-02-26T02:07:58.104774 #23700]  INFO -- : Mailman v0.7.3 started
I, [2016-02-26T02:07:58.105083 #23700]  INFO -- : Rails root found in ., requiring environment...
/Users/Ryzal/Desktop/Sites/rentlord/config/application.rb:59: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
I, [2016-02-26T02:08:07.225640 #23700]  INFO -- : POP3 receiver enabled (@pop.gmail.com).
I, [2016-02-26T02:08:07.266177 #23700]  INFO -- : Polling enabled. Checking every 60 seconds.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/pop.rb:1005:in `check_response_auth': -ERR USER _who_? k19mb6670915wjq (Net::POPAuthenticationError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/pop.rb:905:in `block in auth'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/pop.rb:1012:in `critical'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/pop.rb:904:in `auth'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/pop.rb:566:in `do_start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/pop.rb:536:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/receiver/pop3.rb:36:in `connect'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:139:in `block in polling_loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:137:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:137:in `polling_loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:87:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:15:in `run'
    from script/mailman_server:25:in `<main>'
```

**And this is my mailman_server file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "mailman"

#Mailman.config.logger = Logger.new("log/mailman.log")

Mailman.config.pop3 = {
  server: 'pop.gmail.com', port: 995, ssl: true,
  username: ENV["xxxxxx@gmail.com"],
  password: ENV["xxxxxx"]
}

Mailman::Application.run do
  default do
    begin
      Post.receive_mail(message)
    rescue Exception => e
      Mailman.logger.error "Exception occurred while receiving message:\n#{message}"
      Mailman.logger.error [e, *e.backtrace].join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

Could anybody help? Thanks!

**########################### UPDATE ##########################**

I also have enable POP setting on my gmail account, but still the same error occurs. This is my POP setting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce error only in one case. If I had `username` blank.

If you could use this code for investigation. Put it wherever outside the project, make sure mailman gem is installed and run file twice. Once hardcode user name and second time leave it as `nil`:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "mailman"

username = ''                       
### OR ###
username = 'myownaddress@gmail.com'

puts "Using username='#{username}'..." 
Mailman.config.pop3 = {
  server: 'pop.gmail.com', port: 995, ssl: true,
  username: username, 
  password: 'password'
}
Mailman::Application.run do
  default do
    begin
      puts message 
    rescue Exception => e
      Mailman.logger.error "Exception occurred while receiving message:\n#{message}"
      Mailman.logger.error [e, *e.backtrace].join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

#### Using blank username

```
Using username=''...
I, [2016-03-02T00:01:44.059312 #16088]  INFO -- : Mailman v0.7.3 started
I, [2016-03-02T00:01:44.059400 #16088]  INFO -- : POP3 receiver enabled (@pop.gmail.com).
I, [2016-03-02T00:01:44.070004 #16088]  INFO -- : Polling enabled. Checking every 60 seconds.
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/pop.rb:1005:in
 `check_response_auth': -ERR USER _who_? z184mb105814233wlc (Net::POPAuthenticationError)
```

#### Using correct email.

```
Using username='myownaddress@gmail.com'...

I, [2016-03-02T00:05:35.715465 #16178]  INFO -- : Mailman v0.7.3 started
I, [2016-03-02T00:05:35.715540 #16178]  INFO -- : POP3 receiver enabled (myownaddress@gmail.com@pop.gmail.com).
I, [2016-03-02T00:05:35.726853 #16178]  INFO -- : Polling enabled. Checking every 60 seconds.
I, [2016-03-02T00:06:38.281546 #16178]  INFO -- : Got new message from 'myownaddress@gmail.com' with subject 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642212/popauthenticationerror-mailman-error-when-polling-from-gmail-account'.
Return-Path: <myownaddress@gmail.com>
Received: by 10.79.115.146 with SMTP id y28csa1793673ivf; Tue, 01 Mar 2016 15:06:05 -0800
Received: from mail-lf0-x22f.google.com (mail-lf0-x22f.google.com. [2a00:1450:4010:c07::22f]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id jm5dsi1257241lbc.1.2016.03.01.15.06.05 for 
(...)
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.3124)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642212/popauthenticationerror-mailma=
n-error-when-polling-from-gmail-account=
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no programming solution for this yet, but it's Google's "new" (2014) security policy. Please refer to this Google article:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Hey, I have tried "Allowing less secure apps to access your account" , but still getting the same error. Any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable POP3 access? It is not enabled automatically.

Comment: Oh..how do I do that?

Comment: Hey, i have enabled my POP setting on my gmail, but I still get the same error. Take a look at my update above.

Comment: I suggest to use inline username and password. I can reproduce your problem if I use an empty ENV variable.